# Django - How to set up 2 models with the same fields?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a real estate app with 20 years of sales history.  I want to put the last 2 years of listings into a model that will be actively queried, and the other 18 years into an archived model.

I am using Django 1.11 with Postgresql 9.5

My limited database management knowledge tells me this is called 'horizontal partitioning' or 'sharding'.  Is there a smart way to set this up in Django?  Or do I simply copy and paste the same field names into both `ListingActive` and `ListingArchive`?

```
class ListingActive(models.Model):
    data1 = models.IntegerField()
    data2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    ...
    data100 = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class ListingArchived(models.Model):
    same fields as ListingActive
```

---

Follow-up question.  I want to perform both horizontal partition *and* vertical partition.

Assuming in each `Listing` model, there are a total of 100 fields, but only 10 of them are actively queried.  The other 90 fields are display details which are never queried.

In the end, I want to have 4 total models shown below.  Is there some way to use abstract models, or another method, to set it up?

```
class ListingActiveQuery(models.Model):
    actively_queried_data_1 = models.IntegerField()
    actively_queried_data_2 = models.IntegerField()
    ...
    actively_queried_data_10 = models.IntegerField()
    details = models.OneToOneField(ListingActiveDetails)

class ListingActiveDetails(models.Model):
    data_1 = models.IntegerField()
    data_2 = models.IntegerField()
    ...
    data_90 = models.IntegerField()

class ListingArchivedQuery(models.Model):
    actively_queried_data_1 = models.IntegerField()
    actively_queried_data_2 = models.IntegerField()
    ...
    actively_queried_data_10 = models.IntegerField()
    details = models.OneToOneField(ListingArchivedDetails)

class ListingArchivedDetails(models.Model):
    data_1 = models.IntegerField()
    data_2 = models.IntegerField()
    ...
    data_90 = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: One makes an abstract model containing the fields, and subclass that abstract model to the two real models.

Comment: Why don't you add a field `is_archived = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Is archived?")`? When you do so, you can filter with `Listing.objects.filter(is_archived=False)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically you make an [*abstract* model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) with the fields, and then subclass that abstract model into the two real models. For example:

```
class AbstractDataModel(models.Model):
    data1 = models.IntegerField()
    data2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    # ...
    data100 = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ListingActive(AbstractDataModel):
    pass

class ListingArchived(AbstractDataModel):
    pass
```

**EDIT**

```
class AbstractQuery(models.Model):
    actively_queried_data_1 = models.IntegerField()
    actively_queried_data_2 = models.IntegerField()
    # ...
    actively_queried_data_10 = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class AbstractDetails(models.Model):
    data_1 = models.IntegerField()
    data_2 = models.IntegerField()
    # ...
    data_90 = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ListingActiveQuery(AbstractQuery):
    details = models.OneToOneField(ListingActiveDetails)

class ListingActiveDetails(AbstractDetails):
    pass

class ListingArchivedQuery(AbstractQuery):
    details = models.OneToOneField(ListingArchivedDetails)

class ListingArchivedDetails(AbstractDetails):
    pass
```

Comment: Yes that is what I'm looking for.  However will abstract models affect performance?  The purpose of splitting the table is to increase performance in querying `ListingActive`.  Reading the Django docs, it seems that abstract models use OneToOne connection with all its child models.  If abstract models negate the performance gains from sharding, it defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: No, the loss of performance will be neglegible, if you obtain an attribute in Python, it can be defined at a superclass, so that can take a small amount of time. But compared to the query building process, and query the database, this is insignificant.

Comment: Thank you for that, my question is answered.  I did have a follow-up question regarding doing a vertical partition alongside a horizontal partition - see edited question.  Either way, your answer is accepted.

Comment: @Valachio: you can write a [custom object manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/) with a [`defer`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#defer)

Comment: Further thanks to your edited answer.  My question is fully answered.